# Run JS when screen width is this

Tags: javascript, load, width, screen

I have this js that I want to only run when the screen size is 800 or below, as it enables swiping. Please help I cant figure out away.

```
var snapper = new Snap({
  element: document.getElementById('content')
});
```

and the Snap is linked by

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

```
<script> 

            $(function() {
                var SmartMenu           = $('#SmartMenu');
                    MainMenu            = $('.MainMenu');

                    PortfolioMenu       = $('#Portfolio');
                    PortfolioSubMenu    = $('.subMenu');

                    SmartMenuOpen       = $('#SmartMenuOpen');
                    wrapperHeader   = $('.wrapperHeader-Top');

if(window.innerWidth <= 800) {
                        var snapper = new Snap({
  element: document.getElementById('W')
});
}


                $(SmartMenu).on('click', function(a) {
                    if( snapper.state().state=="left" ){
                    snapper.close();
                } else {
                    snapper.open('left');
                }
                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(window.innerWidth <= 800) {
   // Your code here
}
```

That should do the trick the first time.

**EDIT 1**:
If you want it to change whenever the browser is resized

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
  if(window.innerWidth <= 800) {
    // Your code here
  }
}
```

But do make sure that the code you include will work correctly if called multiple times when the browser is resized.

**EDIT 2** With access to jQuery: #2 to support Snap API and to support init

```
var snapper;

function initSnapper() {
  if($(window).innerWidth() <= 800) {
    if(snapper === undefined) {
      snapper = new Snap({
        element: document.getElementById('W')
      });
    } 
    else {
      snapper.enable();
    }
  }
  else if(snapper !== undefined) {
    snapper.disable();
  }
}


$(window).resize(initSnapper);
initSnapper();
```

This will initialize snapper when the page loads and will call initSnapper when the page is resized.
And you will want to check if snapper exists before checking the state like

```
if( snapper && snapper.state().state=="left" ){
  // snapper code
}
```

Comment: It almost worked, it run it when we go under 800, but after going under 800 and then scale back to more than 800 it do not turn it off, it stay on, is that an Else section we have to add? thanks for your help!

Comment: Also are you using jQuery? If so I will add had to do it in jQuery to my post

Comment: Updated the examples above

Comment: it's not working mate :/ thank you very much for your help! have no idea what to do now

Comment: This may help you help me please: https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js that is what i am using to make the slidding.

Comment: I updated the above example because of a mispelling in the code. Also is it just allowing you swipe when you resize past 800? If so you may need to look into how snap works and if its possible to disable. If it is possible you should be able to put that code in the else and it should work. --- AH taking a look at it now